# Hibernate criteria for a foreign key list

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities:

```
public class Document implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String info;
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>(0);
}

public class Tag implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Document> documents = new HashSet<Document>(0);
}
```

A document may have more than one tag, and each tag can contain many items.
Now I want to do a filter function to find out all the documents that has both `tag1(id = 1)` and `tag2(id = 2)`.

I tried to use these restrictions:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Document.class, "doc")
                           .createAlias("doc.tags", "tag");

List<Document> docList = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("tag.id", 1))
                                 .add((Restrictions.eq("tag.id", 2)).list();
```

but they're not working, the list is empty. Is there a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a tag with id equal to 1 **AND** 2. It's not possible use `Restrictions.in("tag.id", Arrays.asList(1, 2))`

Comment: Restrictions.in() is almost same as disjunctions. This will give me all the document have either tag 1 or tag 2. My condition is 1 && 2.